# Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

Tags: support, bug, chat

That's what I often get prompted with once I'm into my half-dozenth comment. But when I click the link, I'm told the attempt to move it failed. So I carry on writing comments.

How does one 'move a discussion to chat' ? Should I expect this link to do it automagically? Do I need to roll up my sleeves and find how chat works, and copy paste or do something else manually?

I'm logged in and have 80k rep. I have an up to date browser, but it is Chromium (74.0.3729.169), running on Linux Mint 18, would these have anything to do with it?

This last happened at around 2019/05/30 14:40(ish) UTC in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/440856/some-questions-about-an-active-filter-design-using-a-design-tool) question.

Comment: Can you give a link to the most recent post this happened on?

Comment: @W5VO Wouldn't it have been a good idea for me to have included that originally!

Comment: So in theory, it should automatically create the room and copy the comments. There are some documented edge cases where it doesn't work, but those don't appear to be in effect.

Comment: @W5VO It has never worked for me, but only happens every few months, so I'm not unduly inconvenienced, just a bit puzzled as to whether it's a bug in SE, or some weirdness of my configuration. I've participated in other peoples' chat room when they have successfully moved a comment trail.